# Arrange 3 divs depending on the responsive design

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have a similar problem [as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30481793/how-to-arrange-3-divs-in-a-different-way-for-responsive-design), but in my case I want to reorder the `div`s the following way:

[image]

I can use bootstrap or css, but I don't know how.

I'd appreciate your help. Thank you!

EDIT: The question has been marked as duplicate [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33947885/left-column-and-stacked-right-column-using-flexbox-css), but although the question is quite similar, I don't know how to apply that method to my case. I wish the moderators understood that what it seems trivial for them, might not be for the person who writes the question.

Comment: Use display grid for this one.

Comment: I don't see how to fix it using display grid and the question has been closed because it's a duplicate of a solution that suggests display flex. I don't understand it.